# Can't install rdkafka into node module in windows

Tags: node.js, node-modules, librdkafka

I am using lib-rdkafka so that i have to install into node module, unfortunately i cant install it. i am using windows 10 OS but my Linux has no problem for it

Already tried for some solutions like
installing and  added path for nuget and msbuild

tried `npm install`

The screenshot has been attached[image]